# Broken LCD without any visible damage - is that possible?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, broken-screen

I have sent a Samsung Galaxy S6 to a warranty repair - the screen remained black but the phone made sounds. The user of the phone did not report any physical damage to it, the display went blank at once according to himself. The phone had no signs of physical damage on the screen.

The service returned the phone with a statement that the LCD screen has been broken by physical stress and the warranty is thus invalid.

Is that possible? I mean I am not the user of the phone and do not know what exactly happened to the phone before it stopped working but some damage should have been visible on the screen, shouldn't it?

Comment: Do remember than the flex cable connecting the screen to the motherboard is a part of the screen assembly, and is fragile too.

Comment: @AndyYan Perhaps, but the report said: "LCD screen was broken and has to be replaced."

Comment: Concerning AMOLEDs, there is a common symptom where a circular area of the screen first go bad (black), due to factors like external shock, then the circle gradually expands to the extent the screen is unusable. I never saw it extending across the *whole* screen myself, but some pretty large ones are possible.

Comment: The digitiser could have gone bad without cracks on the screen and the service center would like to make more money by replacing both so easiest is to report damaged screen

Comment: @beeshyams But if the digitizer had gone bad without a damage to LCD, something would be visible on the screen after restart or touching buttons?

Comment: Possibly not seen since screen went blank- not sure though

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have your old screen you can inspect it visually and you can see that it's damaged, this usually happens to fragile phones.